# In Jmeter write data to .csv and use it another thread group

Tags: jmeter

I am now trying to write http request response values from a thread group to a csv file using simple data writer. It is a list of values that i want to use it in a sample in another thread group. But, i see an error as below: "cannot read file header line". I am trying inter-Thread Communication post processor but, i would need to use 2 values eg. BookingID and corresponding NAME.
[cannot read file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTc4p.png)

First, the idea was to write the values into jmeter property but, realized it will not work as it would be a list of IDs.

Is there an alternate way to achieve this.

Comment: You can use the inter thread communication plugin to share the values between the thread group. You can pass the two values with a common and read the values from the other thread group. Then split  the values and assign to two variables. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not a problem to write a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (or any other Java [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)) into a JMeter property if you use [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

   - In 1st thread group:

     ```
     def myList = []
     myList.add('foo')
     myList.add('bar')
     props.put('myList', myList
     ```
   - in 2nd thread group:

     ```
     def myList = props.get('myList')
     //do what you need with the list
     ```
2. Using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) you can call [__fifoPut() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/#Functions) as many times as you need, all the values will land into the queue and can be read in another thread even in another thread group